# How to add sonar-golang plugin to Sonarqube on k8

Tags: go, kubernetes, sonarqube

I'm running sonarqube server on a kubernetes cluster.
I want to install [sonar-golang](https://github.com/uartois/sonar-golang) plugin to my server to use its quality profile.

However the installation guide only has it for non k8 sonarqube installations. Is there a way to  install these plugins for [sonarqube on kubernetes](https://SonarSource.github.io/helm-chart-sonarqube)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First exec into the Sonarqube pod and look for the Sonarqube home path e.g $sonarqube/extensions/plugins once you know the exact path then exit from the pod and run this command in your terminal.

```
kubectl cp path-to-your-plugin/plugin.xyz <pod-name>:<pligin.xyz> -c <container-name>
```

If you don't know the container name you can check the pods of Sonarqube with this command `kubectl get pods -n yournamespace` in the result it should show you 2/2 running or 3/3 running. By using the describe command `kubectl describe pod-name -n namespace` you can find the correct name of the Sonarqube container to use in the above command. Once you upload the file successfully restart the Sonarqube deployment and the rest of the steps can be followed as normal installation.